# Ruby's defined? operator

Tags: ruby

I am not quite clear about the operator `defined?`.

For example:

> ```
>  defined? var
> ```

Why not:

> ```
> defined? :var
> defined? 'var'  ## i think these two ways maybe make more sense
> ```

But this operator can also be followed by an expression.

At what stage does this operator execute? At the compile stage, similarly to `sizeof(int)` in C?

Comment: Ruby doesn't have a compile-time. Did you mean the parse time?

Comment: *Why* would those two ways make more sense? Why would you give it a `:symbol` or a string when you can give it the actual **symbol** you're interested in?

Comment: Also, no, it's *nothing* like `sizeof(int)` in C, as the languages a *fundamentally* different, and `defined?` and `sizeof` have absolutely nothing in common in their purpose or implementation.

Comment: `defined? :var` actually couldn't work. If `defined?` was a function, then it would have no access to your local variables by name. It has to be an operator.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't see why `defined? :var` implies that `defined?` would have to be a function.

Comment: @meagar it doesn't, but if if it's an operator, then there's not much reason to use a symbol instead of the variable itself. `attr_xxx` need symbols because they are actually functions running in the class definition scope.

Comment: Ah, I see your point.

Comment: Actually, the last part of this question is very interesting. Usually, when a method is to be executed, all of its arguments are evaluated in advance (but not the block). For `defined?`, its argument is not evaluated. It behaves as if it is taking a block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In different contexts, you want to check things at different levels of expansion. `defined?` is for checking verbatim expression. If you do `defined? :var` or `defined? "var"`, they will always give a truthy value because `:var` and `"var"` are valid Ruby expressions (symbol and string).

If you want to check one-level expansion of expressions, then there are specific methods. In this case, if you want to check if such method exists, you can do `respond_to? :var` or `respond_to? "var"`. If you want to check if such variable exists, then you can do `local_variables.key?(:var)`.

Also, `defined?` is not just for checking a single token. It is also for checking complex expressions like `[1, 2, 3].each{|x| puts x}`. It would be inconvenient if you had to express that in a symbol.

---

The last part of this question is very interesting. Usually, when a method is to be executed, all of its arguments are evaluated in advance (but not the block). For `defined?`, its argument is not evaluated; it is just parsed. It behaves as if it is taking a block. [RDoc](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F) says: *Note that the expression is not executed*. I cannot answer how this is done.

Comment: Local variables are not methods despite being in the same namespace (`\w+`)

Comment: @JanDvorak How is that relevant?

Comment: " In this case, if you want to check if such method exists " -- OP seems to be checking for a local variable, not a method.

Comment: @JanDvorak That may be the case, but how do you know that?

Comment: @sawa if `defined? :var`, since `:var` is a symbol, reflection can be used to check this variable, and it is more like meta programming. But if we use `defined? var`, ( 123 is assigned to var, for example ), i think in runtime, it will be like `defined? 123`, so i guess this process should be done in parse stage and **defined?** must be an operator. i don't know if my understanding is right

Comment: @ruanhao Good point. That is mysterious. `defined?` is indeed a method, and it looks like it is exceptional in not executing its arguments first.

Comment: @sawa **"For defined?, its argument is not evaluated; it is just parsed. It behaves as if it is taking a block. RDoc says: Note that the expression is not executed. I cannot answer how this is done."** ------ So i think this process is more likely done in parse stage, or more like a macro